# file uploaded on ftp server didn't copy complete content

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I am using netftp to upload a file on ftp server and following example to upload a file. My file is created on server but remains empty. My code is as below

```
Sub BeginOpenWriteCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim conn As FtpClient = TryCast(ar.AsyncState, FtpClient)
        Dim istream As Stream = Nothing, ostream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(8192) {}
        Dim read As Integer
        Dim input = Server.MapPath("../UploadedMedia/5.mp4")
        Try
            If conn Is Nothing Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("The FtpControlConnection object is null!")
            End If



            istream = New FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)



            While ((read = istream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                ostream.Write(buf, 0, read)

            End While

            ostream = conn.EndOpenWrite(ar)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            If istream IsNot Nothing Then
                istream.Close()
            End If

            If ostream IsNot Nothing Then
                ostream.Close()
            End If

            m_reset.[Set]()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has similar problem using ftp4j. I uploaded file to server, but the uploaded file had a little different size. 
The solution was type of transmission. 
There was ascii and binary and you had to select correct transfer type.
I suggest searching in your library documentation.